# Bad idea to create a folder for every user?

Tags: php, apache

I am wondering if it would be a bad idea to create a folder for every user. So any images for each user would be accessed with img.mysite.com/UserId/image.jpg

Comment: You can instead put all pics in a single folder, and associated every picture with it's owner in the database, and use clean urls if needed!

Comment: Could those who say that it's a "terrible idea", please explain why it's such a bad idea? I personally don't see why this would be an issue on an ext4 filesystem, for example.

Comment: well the main issue is the number of photos is going to grow exponentially. So i didnt want them all stuck in one folder. Adams answer does seem to help with that issue as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could grow to be a huge number of directories, so take caution as [some filesystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4#Features) limit the number of subdirectories in a single directory. It is common to break up generated content into multiple directories. You could do it by date, or break up some identifier (a hash, or the image's autoincremented ID number) to create a deeper directory structure. Example:

- avatars/000/ (images 1-999)
- avatars/001/ (images 1000-1999)
- avatars/002/ (images 2000-2999)

AKA the directory prefix is `floor(ID / 1000)`.

There's probably a case for abstracting your URIs from your filesystem anyway, so it doesn't really matter where the files are stored on the backend, except to you as a programmer.

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely bad idea I will say from my experience
In recent past I was working on one application which was based on social networking
And It has around 15000+ users now.

Also I am managing that site currently.

Problems with this is you will find it cool at first to manage but later it will be a issue.
Always have to keep track of permissions.
Creation and deletion of folder with respect to your database to achieve synchronisation.
Also If you are on shared hosting, many hosting providers they don't show all the folders with any File Manager.Maximum number of folder that can be seen through File Managers is 2000 with customer care support you only get access to first 10000 folder.
Also Non-Ascii name for folder will as that of database will be another issue.

Which will be a great problem for you later.

I will suggest not to go with this way for sure.

Comment: you can split folders, silly. nobody asks you to create all 15k in the same directory.

Comment: It would also be a problem when you have non-ASCII names, depending on the filesystem. (But why introduce the complexity?)

Comment: there is no problem to name folders after numerical id either. it's just your fault if you use a username

Comment: Adding numerical Id is again add on bro...And will noway adds to identify user

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not the best idea.

If the only purpose of the separate folders is so that you can have 'friendly' URLs in the structure you suggest, then I recommend you search for **URL Rewriting** instead.

If you're trying to solve some other problem, post a comment and let us know.

Comment: not the only reason but definitely one of them. my other concern is if there is a problem with having one directory that will be housing all photos. The amount of photos is going to be 100,000+

Comment: If it needs to be human-readable, i.e. some poor person will have to manually browse for a particular photo in a folder of 100,000s then I'd agree with the multi-folder option. But as it (sounds like) it's a computer's job, then it can handle the task.

Answer (score 1):

No reason why it would be an issue from a performance reason. From an organizational perspective, it's cleaner than just throwing them all together into the same folder.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a resources issue, since some servers allow only a specific number of folders?

Comment: if you're accessing that directory with ls or via ftp for some reason then listing the directory contents may be slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be better format:
`http://img.mysite.com/userid_imageid.jpg`

Then you can do database like this:

tables `users` and `imgs`

Comment: Yes, thats a good structure. 
Replacing original image names is often needed.

Often you will find imagelinks like: fgh6tfjj65zg47tcjtrd.jpg
That is to *try* to avoid direct access to images - for privacy or mass-grabbing.

And I want to mention it is a good idea to use a "cdn" - content delivery domain to serve static content, like images.

Answer (score 0):

Use one folder on your ftp and make a good and solid database where all photos of the same person are linked together. Not so hard :)

Answer (score 0):

For a smaller site, it's not a terrible idea, with one caveat:

You **MUST** abstract the file creation/deletion handling into one mechanism!

Make sure that all your code uses this mechanism, which should be able to store and retrieve and delete, and that's it. Then, in the future, if you want to change how you store your files, you can do it really easily.

**P.S.** When I say all your code, I really mean *all* your code. For instance, I'd have any GET that matches

```
^img.mysite.com/(\w+)/(\w+\.jpg)$
```

handled by a single method, which calls the mechanism I described above.